# Does Skype running in the background use more battery life than other background running iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, skype

I have noticed that I can receive skype calls and messages on my iPhone for a while now. Does Skype simply stay sign-ed in until I restart my iPhone and does it use the same amount of battery as other apps with notifications WHEN running in the background.

i.e. if I have Facebook with notifications and Skype with notifications running in the background, do these apps/notifications use the same amount of battery?

Comment: +1 question. My understanding is that it uses *some* more battery, but not a huge amount.

Comment: Are you in an active Skype call when it's backgrounded and trying to do other things? In that case: yes, Skype sucks battery like nothing else I've seen before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple limits what can run in the background to ensure battery life is not dramatically reduced. Skype will be constrained to the same restrictions that all other App Store apps must follow.

Given this, it is fair to assume Skype uses no more than any other Internet telephony app running in the background on your iPhone.

Fraser Speirs's article may be helpful in better understanding [how background processes work on your iPhone](http://speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html).

Comment: Very helpful and very interesting!